# how to use currency field from Lookup field in Calculated Field of Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm setting up a new project in Dynamics crm, My entity name is "Complaint", 
also I have another Entity , it's Name is: "Project", 
and we have a "Project" Lookup field in Complaint. 
another field of "Complaint" is "Calculated Cost"(Currency) .
we need to have this formula:   `Calculated_Cost = Chargeable_ManHour(Decimal) * Project.ManHourCost(Currency)`

but it did not work.

so I check this one:  `Calculated_Cost = Project.ManHourCost`

but it did not work again.

so I check another one: `Calculated_Cost = Project.SomeDecimalField(Decimal)`

this one worked.

I think that this problem may related to Currency DataType and may we have a Cast Function for this, anybody have a Solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I bet your test record doesn’t have the “Currency” lookup field set to a value. This is a special field that is not normally shown on the form and it is added automatically the first time you add a “Currency” type field to the entity. If you already have records in the database, those records will have a null Currency lookup field. New records will automatically set their Currency lookup to the system Default Currency, but old records that do not have a Currency lookup set will not calculate correctly because they don’t know which Currency to use (even if you only use one Currency).

The fix is to go back and set the Currency lookup for all existing records after you add the first Currency type field to an entity. You can use the multi-edit feature or a workflow (after you have added the Currency lookup to the form) or you could write a quick script to do it if you have lots of records to update.

So my theory is that you created this entity, created some test records, then you added the first Currency field (which is calculated). Your existing test record now has a null Currency lookup, so your custom calculated Currency field cannot calculate a value. You could easily test this by just creating a new test record and see if the calculation works on the new record, since the Currency lookup will be set automatically going forward.